# Equivalence of Perforce "p4 sync -p ...@Changelist" in Git

Tags: git, perforce

In Perforce, you can actually create a clientspec (workspace), and use "-p" option when syncing down Perforce code. This way it doesn't touch the file table in Perforce server, and makes the syncing much faster.  It's basically copy and paste files from the Perforce server.

We are experimenting such operation on Git side, but couldn't find an exact replica of this Perforce command.

Is there an equivalence of this?

I know `git reset --hard <commit>` will work, but that's if you already used `git clone` and obtained a local copy of the files.  In our cases, assume we never run `git clone` in the local machine.

I'm asking in this situation because I'm doing SCM release build, and the source code from Git need to sync down to the build machine at a specific SHA, but doesn't have `git clone` ran in the past.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure git-daemon to allow the "upload-archive" service (see the git-daemon manpage), and this allows for a client to simply request an archive of a particular snapshot from the git repository, using the `git archive --remote` command, rather than having to download the whole database.

e.g. this will download a snapshot of some project called "cmstool" at version 1.0.0 from a remote server:

```
git archive --format=tar \
            --prefix=cmstool-1.0.0/ \
            --remote=git://git/cmstool.git v1.0.0 | tar xf -
```

Comment: Note that this is the best way to do it IF you agree never to use git submodules. You can't run git submodule init/update on a checkout performed using git archive since no git metadata will be available.

Comment: I guess you could write something to look at the .gitmodules file downloaded and use that to grab submodules recursively? It certainly adds to the complexity considerably from being practically a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

git is not designed to only get *specific* versions of files, but the history.  Is there really a problem with doing a `git clone` first and `git fetch` when updates need to happen?  Updates use diffs so can be much faster than copying all the files, and a git repository is often not that much larger than the current state.

That said, there are a few approaches to not copy all the history:

1. `git clone --depth 1` will only get the recent history, but it still fetches all branches.  It also is not a terribly useful clone, as many common operations will not work.  This may not be a problem in your use-case.
2. You can set up an ephemeral branch with only one commit that has the state you want to copy.  Then the client does `git init; git remote add -t <branch> origin <url>; git fetch origin/branch; git checkout origin/branch`
3. `git archive` can create a snapshot which can be downloaded as a separate file, and then extracted.

Comment: `git clone --depth=1` is what I initially tested, but it doesn't work well because it always get the HEAD. That's not what our current SCM machine can do.

Comment: option #2 is fine, but we are talking about 20 builds everyday at a different time, at different changes (SHA)

Comment: for option #3, how fast is `git archive` ran?  `git clone --depth=1` is usually taking about 2 mins to download our source in optimal situation.

Comment: for #1, you could set up another repo on the same machine sharing the object pool (so no copying), and point its HEAD appropriately.

Comment: Hi wnoise,

That basically means I will have to create a new repo every time I started a build which has different change all the time. :( And we are talking about 20 builds a day.

Comment: You can actually do it with just a new branch, rather than a full repository. #1 not only gets the HEAD, but all branches.  It just automatically checks out the HEAD.  If you want a specific SHA, you'll have to point a branch at it, and then check it out.  Really though, what's the problem with having a `git clone` on the build machine?

Comment: In any case, creating a new repo or branch is not hard -- it is completely scriptable.

Comment: Without having `git clone` on the build machine is a requirement set by other teams which I have no control over on changing it. To get things done, I will have to find an alternative solution.